# Figuring out Big(o)

Tags: time, complexity-theory

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
            {
                cout << j << endl;
                result++;
            }
        }
```

Running this code say for 5 it runs a total of 30 times. I know the outer loop runs N. the inner loop though is giving me some trouble since it's not `n*n` but `i*i` and I haven't seen one like this before trying to figure out `T(n)`, and Big(O).

Comment: Seems it's O(n^3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm is `O(n^3)`: To realise this we have to figure out how often the inner code

```
cout << j << endl;
result++;
```

is executed. For this we need to sum up `1*1+2*2+...+n*n = n^3/3+n^2/2+n/6` which is a well known result (see e.g. [Sum of the Squares of the First n Natural Numbers](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm)). Thus `O(T(n)) = O(1*1+2*2+...+n*n) = O(n^3)` and the (time) complexity of the algorithm is therefore `O(n^3)`.

**Edit:** If you're wondering why this is sufficient (see also Example 4 in [Time complexity with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168379/7444219)) it is helpful to rewrite your code as a single loop so we can see that the loops add a constant amount of instructions (for each run of the inner code):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while(i < n) {
    cout << j << endl;
    result++;
    if(j < i * i) j++; //were still in the inner loop
    else {//start the next iteration of the outer loop
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Thus the two loops 'add' the two comparisons plus the if-statement which simply makes the conditional jumps and their effects more explicit.